# react.js how to avoid parent state update on child component cancel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react.js project I have parent and child components (Page like parent and Modal with input like child). I receive data in parent by ajax request and pass it for input from parent to child and fill the child state with it. Also in child component I have 2 buttons: Submit and Cancel. Conside the following code:

```
**Parent**

render() {
    const { projectAux } = this.props;
    return (
        <ProjectNameFormModal
                projectAux={projectAux}
                onVisibleChange={e => this.onVisibleProjectNameFormModalChange(e)}
                visible={this.state.editProjectNameModalVisible}
            />
    )

}

**Child**

import React from 'react';

import {Button, Checkbox, Form, Input, List, Modal, Select} from "antd";

class ProjectNameFormModal extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        projectAux: props.projectAux,
        visible: props.visible

    }
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    if(this.state.projectAux != nextProps.projectAux){
        this.setState({
            projectAux:  nextProps.projectAux,
            visible: nextProps.visible
        });
    }
    return true;

}

handleProjectNameInputChange = e => {
    let current_state  = this.state;
    current_state.projectAux[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(current_state);
}

handleCancelSubmitProjectNameUpdate = e => {
    this.props.onVisibleChange(false);
}

handleSubmitProjectNameUpdate = e => {
    console.log(' in handleSubmitProjectNameUpdate');
    this.setState({...this.state, visible: false});
    this.props.onVisibleChange(false);
}

render() {

    return (
        <Modal
            title='Edit project Name'
            visible={this.props.visible}
            bodyStyle={{}}//height:"800px"
            onSave={{}}
            maskClosable={false}
            onCancel={this.handleCancelSubmitProjectNameUpdate}
            footer={[
                <Button key="back" onClick={this.handleCancelSubmitProjectNameUpdate}>
                    Cancel
                </Button>,
                <Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmitProjectNameUpdate}>
                    Save
                </Button>,
            ]}
        >
            <div>
                <Input placeholder="ProjectName"
                       name="name"
                       onChange={this.handleProjectNameInputChange}
                       value={this.state.projectAux && (this.state.projectAux.name)}
                />
            </div>
        </Modal>
     );
   }
}

export default ProjectNameFormModal;
```

So the problem is when I enter some new data to input and then press `Cancel` button, I have also my Parent state updated to the new data which I definetely dont want to happen. When Cancel is pressed, no updates to the parent state should occur but it happens. Btw, parent state does not update when I enter new symbols into input. I tried to use spread operator as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053440/react-js-why-child-component-change-parent-state) but it did not work.

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome, thank you.

Comment: 'I have also my Parent state updated to the new data which I definetely dont want to happen."  -- what are you referring to here? I don't see any parent state at all, much less parent state being updated.

Comment: it is a `projectAux` variable which comes from `this.props` in parent component. It is received through ajax and then passed down to child. In child component (form input) it is being updated by user, but when user hits `cancel` button, I see in parent component that it is updated to user input actually made. The only thing that should be updated is `visible` child prop when user hits `cancel`